# netty http server and python client sending a requests runs only once

Tags: java, python, http, netty

I have created an http server using netty and java. It takes an http request to login a user. I use a python console application created for this purpose that makes a request to the http server with username and password as parameters, and server responds with a json object `{"result":true}` e.g for a successful login.

I use requests library to handle requests and responses from and to the client. The request works as I get the response back and the user is authenticated and logged in. But when I try to request a user login once again, I don't get a response. The request reaches the server and the login function of the server gets called (as I can see in console). But the response never comes to the client.

```
command = raw_input()
while command != "exit":
    if command == "login":
        username = raw_input("Username:")
        password = raw_input("Password:")
        login_user(username, password)
    command = raw_input()
```

login function

```
def login_user(username, password):
    url = "http://10.154.196.99:8000/"
    url = url + 'login?username=' + username + "&password=" + password
    LOG.debug("logging in using url: " + url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    LOG.debug(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print "Logged in successfully"
        LOG.debug(response.content)
    else:
        print "Login was unsuccessful"
```

First time i get the login successfully, second time it hangs on the get call. Server does get to the response. What could be wrong?

EDIT: Just noticed I get the following exception on the server side

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```